# Why in LD_PRELOAD exploit we call unsetenv(LD_PRELOAD)?

Tags: exploit, c, privilege-escalation, library

Why to exploit LD_PRELOAD like is shown here https://touhidshaikh.com/blog/?p=827 in the .c file the first instruction is unsetenv(LD_PRELOAD)? Is it a routine action which all shared libraries do? Or what? I've tried to run the exploit without unsetenv and the terminal was "hanging" not receiving ^C ^Z ^D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Environment variables such as `LD_PRELOAD` are inherited by child processes. The linked example overrides the `_init` symbol to invoke a shell using `system("/bin/bash")`. If the environment variable would not have been cleared, then it would effectively be stuck in an "infinite loop" when invoking `system`.

If you watch your process list (using `ps aux` for example), you will see a bunch of shell processes. The system library function creates a new process and executes `/bin/sh -c "...."`. Every time, `_init` is executed.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is the _init the function called when a shared library starts?

Comment: Apparently it is called when it is loaded, see https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/miscellaneous.html#INIT-AND-CLEANUP